# call navigationcontroller with modalview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I have a problem, I have made this:

```
Impostazioni *impostazioni=[[Impostazioni alloc] initWithNibName:@"Impostazioni" bundle:nil]; 
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:aiuto animated:YES];
```

But I want to preserve the navigation bar in this modality:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:aiuto animated:YES];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar.backItem  setTitle:@"iCalory"];
```

And I want use presentModalView how can I this? thanks

Answer (score 3):

To add navigation controller in your code,

```
 Impostazioni *impostazioni=[[Impostazioni alloc] initWithNibName:@"Impostazioni" bundle:nil]; 

 UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: impostazioni] autorelease];

 [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:navigationController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add your view controller to a new navigation controller and present the navigation controller modally:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: aiuto] autorelease];
[self presentModalViewController navigationController];
```